# Python accessing attribute of wrong class

Tags: python, namespaces

I am currently facing the issue, that my Python script is accessing an attribute of a wrong class. This is obviously regarding to some namespace conflicts within my project.

Let me show you my current implementation:

Project structure (everything in the same package):

```
|- bot_test_project    
   |- bot.py
   |- message.py
```

bot.py:

```
import logging

from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters, CommandHandler

API_KEY = "please enter your api key here"

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO) logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

class Bot:
    def __init__(self):
        updater = Updater(API_KEY)
        self.__bot = updater.bot

        dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
        dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", self.receive_command, pass_user_data=True))
        dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, self.receive_message, pass_user_data=True))

        updater.start_polling()

    def receive_command(self, bot, update, user_data):
        print(update.message.id)

    def receive_message(self, bot, update, user_data):
        print(update.message.id)


Bot()
```

message.py:

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, id=None, text=None, photo=None):
        self.__id = id
        self.__text = text
        self.__photo = photo

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self.__id

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self.__text

    @property
    def photo(self):
        return self.__photo
```

However, I am currently getting the following error message:

```
2018-07-13 23:13:35,915 - telegram.ext.dispatcher - ERROR - An uncaught error was raised while processing the update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/dispatcher.py", line 279, in process_update
    handler.handle_update(update, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/commandhandler.py", line 173, in handle_update
    return self.callback(dispatcher.bot, update, **optional_args)
  File "/bot.py", line 23, in receive_command
    print(update.message.id)
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'id'
```

receive_message() is actually a callback function of a third-party library (telegram-bot). Therefore all the function parameters are related to the third-party library classes.

For some reason, Python is looking for the `text` attribute in my local class, but it should access the update's class attribute. I haven't even imported my local class `message`.

I am currently using Python 3.6

EDIT:

```
print(type(update.message))
<class 'telegram.message.Message'>

print(dir(update.message))
['ATTACHMENT_TYPES', 'MESSAGE_TYPES', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__metaclass__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_effective_attachment', '_id_attrs', '_parse_html', '_parse_markdown', '_quote', 'audio', 'author_signature', 'bot', 'caption', 'caption_entities', 'caption_html', 'caption_html_urled', 'caption_markdown', 'caption_markdown_urled', 'channel_chat_created', 'chat', 'chat_id', 'connected_website', 'contact', 'date', 'de_json', 'delete', 'delete_chat_photo', 'document', 'edit_caption', 'edit_date', 'edit_reply_markup', 'edit_text', 'effective_attachment', 'entities', 'forward', 'forward_date', 'forward_from', 'forward_from_chat', 'forward_from_message_id', 'forward_signature', 'from_user', 'game', 'group_chat_created', 'invoice', 'left_chat_member', 'location', 'media_group_id', 'message_id', 'migrate_from_chat_id', 'migrate_to_chat_id', 'new_chat_members', 'new_chat_photo', 'new_chat_title', 'parse_caption_entities', 'parse_caption_entity', 'parse_entities', 'parse_entity', 'photo', 'pinned_message', 'reply_audio', 'reply_contact', 'reply_document', 'reply_html', 'reply_location', 'reply_markdown', 'reply_media_group', 'reply_photo', 'reply_sticker', 'reply_text', 'reply_to_message', 'reply_venue', 'reply_video', 'reply_video_note', 'reply_voice', 'sticker', 'successful_payment', 'supergroup_chat_created', 'text', 'text_html', 'text_html_urled', 'text_markdown', 'text_markdown_urled', 'to_dict', 'to_json', 'venue', 'video', 'video_note', 'voice']
```

EDIT:
For everyone who is wondering if the `update` object actually contains a `message.text` attribute - please take a look [here](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html) to convince yourself.

Comment: what are `type(update.message)` and `dir(update.message)`?

Comment: There are no "namespaces" used here.  You're looking in the `update` object for a variable (or property) named `message` and expecting that to have a variable/property named `text`.  It's not there.

Comment: we need more information. can you provide more code and full error traceback please?

Comment: @MoxieBall see my updated question please.

Comment: @MikeHousky well it is there as you can see here https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html - it has already worked until I have introduced my message class

Comment: @nosklo I have simplified the code but there actually isn't more to show which would be relevant. As described in the telegram-bot documentation, the "update" attr contains a message object which contains a text https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.update.html - I cant access it anymore since I have introduced my own message.py class in my project...

Comment: Your own message.py is probably unrelated @Druux

Comment: @Druux I edited my answer based on my testings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your own message.py is unrelated, as the class is coming from `telegram.message` which is the telegram module.

The [documentation for `.text`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#telegram.Message.text) says it is optional - maybe the message you're dealing with has no text?

EDIT: 
I have created a new token, and tried running your code, and I can't reproduce your issues. Here are my findings:

- your own `message.py` **is completely unrelated**. Deleting it from the project does nothing. Adding a syntax error inside it does nothing. It is not even being imported. I put a jpg file named `message.py` instead, and nothing happens.
- I tried printing `update.message.text` and it works fine here! While `update.message.id` fails, it seems that `id` is not in the documentation for the `Message` class that you linked. I'm using `update.message.message_id` instead and it works fine here!
- I modified the function to answer the message, as below, and it works fine, as you can see in the screenshot:

Modification:

```
def receive_message(self, bot, update, user_data):
    bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.message.chat_id,
        text="You said {} with id {}".format(
            update.message.text, update.message.message_id
        ),
    )
```

[image: Testing the bot in telegram web]

Comment: Good thought, but it isn't unrelated in my case. The text isn't empty. It works if I am deleting my message.py. It even works if I am adding the 'text' attribute to my message.py. Such a weird behaviour...

Comment: @Druux if it is really using your `message.py` then it is really odd, we have to find out why! I can't deduce what is wrong from the information you provided. To do that we really need more code. If you're willing to share more code I would take a look later - We need to know things like how your project is structured (the full folder and file structure), how you're running it (what is the main script) and how you're defining the callback to the library, those things can help determine how your class is getting inside the other library somehow. Maybe upload the entire project to a repository?

Comment: Is your project named `telegram` too?

Comment: sure. I will manage to provide you the entire code and will get back to you. thanks a lot @nosklo

Comment: no the name of my project nor the file isn't `telegram`

Comment: I have added a new answer above. If you want to debug it, you will have to get an Telegram bot api key (its very fast to setup). But I am pretty sure this isn't a library related issue... @nosklo